# Exclude sitemap.xml from htaccess

Tags: php, sitemap, sitemap.xml

When I try to access by using /sitemap.xml it just loads the homescreen with no change in URL, whatever I give next to slash it gives me the homepage.

I think sitemap.xml is not found so it shows the homepage. If I don't use htacess it works.

This the code of htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [NC]
```

Comment: sorry its an typing mistake it does work when i dont use htacess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to exclude the sitemap.xml from the rewrite rule that currently catches it, for example by [adding a rewrite condition](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) in front testing not being the sitemap filename:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [NC]
```